# Passing prepared statements in MySQLi as function arguments

Tags: php, mysqli

Here I want to pass the prepared statements as arguments of *test* function which should display the query results.But the code below doesn't work,because it may lack something that I don't know.What should I do in order to display results by the *test* function:

```
<?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

  /*check connection*/
  if(mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    printf("connection failed: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  /*create prapared statement*/

  $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("select id from posts");
  $stmt2 =$mysqli->prepare("select username from members where id=?");

  $stmt1->execute(); 

  $stmt1->store_result(); 

  $stmt1->bind_result($ID);

  /*bind params*/
  $stmt2->bind_param('i',$id);

  /*bind results*/
  $stmt2->bind_result($username);


   while($stmt1->fetch())
   {    
      /*set params*/
      $id =$ID;

      /*execute prapared statement*/
      $stmt2->execute();$stmt2->store_result();                 

   }

  test($stmt1,$stmt2);//function call  

  function test($stmt1,$stmt2)
  {

   while($stmt1->fetch())
   {     
      while($stmt2->fetch())
      {
        echo 'Username: '.$username.'<br/>';
      }     

   }     

  }

?>
```

Comment: You have already `fetch`ed all `$stmt1` results. `fetch`ing them again won't work unless you rewind the result set.

Comment: thank you.. but how should I do this? @NiettheDarkAbsol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this way could be not the lightweight solution but you can reset the result pointer with the `mysqli_result::data_seek()` method and as you need again the result variable you have to rebind it:

```
function test($stmt1, $stmt2)
{
    $stmt1->data_seek(0);

    while($stmt1->fetch())
    {
        $stmt2->data_seek(0);
        $stmt2->bind_result($username);

        while($stmt2->fetch())
        {
            echo 'Username: '.$username.'<br/>';
        }     
    }   
}

test($stmt1, $stmt2);
```

An option could be to store in an array the binded results inside the while, and then use this array subsequently as many times as you want; However everything depends on your needs.

**Source:** http://www.php.net/manual/it/mysqli-result.data-seek.php

EDIT -------------------

I just suggested using an array to avoid reusing resource only for looping the same data.

Anyway, it may depends on your env but in case you have [mysqlnd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) driver installed, you can do something like this:

```
$res1 = $stmt1->get_result(); // here you can use get_result() to get the resultset

$myAy = array();

while($row = $res1->fetch_array())
{
    $myAy[] = $row;
}

var_dump($myAy);
```

or another way could be something like this:

```
...

$myAy = array();

while ($stmt1->fetch()) 
{
    $id = $ID;
    $myAy['id'] = $ID;

    ...
}

while ($stmt2->fetch()) 
{
    $myAy['user'] = $username;
}

var_dump($myAy);
```

**Just my two cents...**

Comment: thank you.... could you plz give a hint on how the two result sets can be stored in two arrays @ilpaijin